# How to write an octal value in Python 2 & 3

Tags: python

I need to write 0644 (0o644) in Python 2 and 3 compatible way. How to do it? The only ideas I have is to parse this from string or convert into hex or decimal. That's not human-readable. I don't mind slow speed, it's called just once.

Comment: [`0o644` is Python 2 *and* 3 compatible](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#octal-constants)…!?

Comment: @deceze 0o644 isn't compatible with Python 2.5 for instance. But we're talking ancient history

Comment: So how far backwards compatible do you need it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`0o644` is compatible with both python2 and python3

Answer (score 12):

Very old python 2 versions ([< 2.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/#transition-from-2-6-to-3-0)) don't accept the octal prefix in `0o644`.

If you *really* need to be compliant with python 2.5 or earlier you can parse an octal string with `int`

```
int('644',8)
```

note that compatibility tricks catching `ImportError`, `NameError`, ... exceptions don't work here because you cannot catch the `SyntaxError`, the parser doesn't let that happen:

```
# that doesn't work
try:
    x = 0644   # either crashes here
except SyntaxError:
    x = 0o644  # or here
# that doesn't work
```