# Does Python 2.x always return a string for print statements?

Tags: python, types, printf, python-2.x

I was messing around with both Python 3.8 and 2.7 and found out that the print function in Python 3 doesn't allow leading zeros in print. See below:

```
    >>> print(01)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(01)
           ^
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

I suppose this happens because Python 3.x differentiate data types even when printing, this is why the following works:

```
>>> print('01')
01
```

I explicitly asked to print a string. Though in Python 2.7 there is no error with the following statement:

```
>>> print '01'
01
```

It just returns what I asked. Does it mean that Python 2.x always converts print values into strings?

Comment: It seems like you're putting quotes around the value in all but the first case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In original python 2, `print` is a statement, and does not `return` a value at all.

```
>>> x=print 'hi'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x=print 'hi'
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If you use the future-compatible print function in python 2.7, say, it behaves exactly like Python 3.

In Python 3, `print`, a function, always returns `None`. It prints to a file (often the standard output), but the value returned from the function is `None`.

```
>>> x=print(1)
1
>>> x
>>> type(x)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

As for `1` vs `01`, in Python 2, a number with a leading zero is octal:

```
>>> 010
8
```

This syntax is illegal in Python 3, so you get `SyntaxError: invalid token`. This happens before the `print` statement ever sees what's going on, so it has nothing to do with `print`.

If you want to [write a number in octal in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345204/how-to-write-an-octal-value-in-python-2-3), the correct syntax is `0o...` as in:

```
>>> 0o10
8
```

Comment: Thanks!

As you may have noticed by the lack of comprehension of fundamental concepts, I'm a newbie. So this was really helpful.

Comment: @FlavioHF I recommend you don't [cut your teeth](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+your+teeth) on an obsolete version of Python, if you can help it :)